# Time Complexity when inner loop starts with j=2

Tags: c, time-complexity

I get `O(n^2 logn)` as output of the following code. Yet I am unable to understand why?

```
int unknown(int n) {
    int i, j, k = 0;
    for (i = n / 2; i <= n; i++)
        for (j = 2; j <= n; j = j * 2)
            k = k + n / 2;
    return k;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean you "get O(n^2 logn) as output of the following code?" Who gives you that "output?"

Answer (score 2):

A fixed constant starting point will make no difference to the inner loop in terms of complexity.

Starting at two instead of one will mean one less iteration but the *ratio* is still a logarithmic one.

Think in terms of what happens when you double `n`. This adds one more iteration to that loop regardless of whether you start at one or two. Hence it's `O(log N)` complexity.

However, you should keep in mind that the *outer* loop is an `O(N)` one since the number of iteratations is proportional to `N`. That makes the function as a whole `O(N log N)`, not the `O(N2 log N)` you posit.